# Accelerometer in Game Closure

Tags: javascript, ios, html, gameclosure

Is it possible to use accelerometer/motion sensing with Game Closure(http://www.gameclosure.com/) framework? I tried googling it everywhere and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Well after browsing the API and got to the [device](http://docs.gameclosure.com/api/device.html) page.. There doesn't seem to be an option like that, so i think it's a no for the moment.

Comment: But, on the other hand, it's javascript, so shouldn't I be able to use this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/#toc-usingDM somehow?

Comment: Hmmm didn't know that HTML5/JS could do that, then you won't know unless you try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for Android, but on iOS, there's currently not a large set of device API access yet (at least not that's public in GC's docs). The example on that html5rocks tutorial doesn't directly apply because when GC is deployed as an app, it is not using a browser window or webview. The "window" object is much different and does not have the same methods and properties.

The GC staff has said in their forums that they are working on a guide to extending the native aspects of the engine, which I'm hoping will clarify how to access more of the native device API's, including the accelerometer.